# Azure Blob Storage - Content Type Setting on Download and Upload

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I am trying to upload a word document to blob storage using C#. The code snippet is as below:

```
var blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(connectionString);
var containerClient = blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient(container);
containerClient.CreateIfNotExists(PublicAccessType.None);
var blobClient = containerClient.GetBlobClient(documentName);
using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream({Binary of the File}))
{
    var headers = new BlobHttpHeaders() { ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document" };
    await blobClient.UploadAsync(memoryStream, httpHeaders: headers).ConfigureAwait(false);
}
```

The document gets uploaded successfully to the Blob Storage. I can see that the content type is also being set properly while looking through Azure Storage Explorer. But, when i try to access this document (using document URL) through browser (chrome), it downloads the file as unknown file.

I tried the same by uploading a word document through Azure Storage Explorer. This file gets downloaded as word document while downloading it through browser.

Any idea what is going wrong?

Comment: Will it be possible to share the actual blob URL?

Comment: did you try other browser, EDGE or IE?

Answer (score 1):

As you see the figure below, the `Content-Type` header is stored as a property in the `Blob Properties`, so it will be set into the headers of the download response and then it will be recognized as a word file while download by browser.

[image]

So when you upload a word file, it's necessary to set the `ContentType` property for a blob via [`BlobBaseClient.SetHttpHeaders(BlobHttpHeaders, BlobRequestConditions, CancellationToken) Method`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.storage.blobs.specialized.blobbaseclient.sethttpheaders?view=azure-dotnet) or [`BlobBaseClient.SetHttpHeadersAsync(BlobHttpHeaders, BlobRequestConditions, CancellationToken) Method`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.storage.blobs.specialized.blobbaseclient.sethttpheadersasync?view=azure-dotnet#Azure_Storage_Blobs_Specialized_BlobBaseClient_SetHttpHeadersAsync_Azure_Storage_Blobs_Models_BlobHttpHeaders_Azure_Storage_Blobs_Models_BlobRequestConditions_System_Threading_CancellationToken_).

And then to write the `Content-Type`header of the headers of a download response with the value of `contentType` below by yourself on your server app.

```
Response<BlobProperties> response = await blobClient.GetPropertiesAsync();
var contentType = response.Value.ContentType
```

Or the download response from a blob url with sas token which headers default include the `ContentType` property as the `Content-Type` header.